# White package icons in my Eclipse's package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting these strange white package icons in my testing project. From what I've seen @ http://jamie.ideasasylum.com/images/icons.pdf, they signal "empty packages", but I  don't know why.

[image]

My `src/` folder is set is includedin the build path, so I don't get what the problem might be:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: **Empty package** with **subpackages**. Nothing wrong.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is most likely because you have chosen hierarchical package views. The hierarchical package view will show empty package icons for packages without any classes.

[image: Hierarchical Package view in Eclipse]

Switching to flat package views will allow Eclipse to display only packages that have classes in them.

Answer (score 1):

Create at least one class in the 'empty' package 'white package' and refresh the project, the color should change to Golden.

When Package does not contain any class, then the color is white.

Comment: Simple Answer.. Voted Up.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the folder structure, src in the picture.

[image]

2. Go to build path and do exclude
   [image]
3. Output:

[image].