# Eclipse ADT - project structure changed showing blank packages

Tags: android, eclipse, package

I am trying to rename my eclipse android project. I have tried Android Tools -> Rename Application Package. It gave me an error occurred see log.

I can't find any logs and suddenly this happen my project structure shows some blank and garbage packages as shown in picture.I tried deleting it but deleting them deletes my source code too.Any idea will be very helpful..

[image: Snap for eclipse project structure]

Answer (score 1):

You can rename classes, packages and projects by right clicking on the class/package/project and choose: `Refactor -> Rename`. Check the `Update references` box to make sure all references to the project/class are also changed.

Comment: tried but not working and  I dont know from where i got those blank packages :(

Comment: A workaround could be to go to your eclipse workspace folder and rename the project folder. Now, start eclipse and create a new project with the new name. An auto-import option will be available.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is totally ok.

A java package corresponds with an folder.
When a package/folder is empty eclipse will show it as "white boxed" without content (no arrow).

Example:
The class "**AClass**" in "**com.me.pckg**" corrensponds with

**com/me/pckg/AClass.java**

This means folder "**com**" and "**me**" contains no files. Eclipse represents this a "white boxed" packages (**com** and **com.me**). Package "**com.me.pckg**" is not empty.

Aware eclipse does not show the package structure **NOT** as hierarchical as you expect it in a file system view.

Vice versa if you put some file/-structure in your project eclipse will show new folders a packages. This happens after a refresh or a restart of eclipse, the later may be perceived as a sudden action.

If you want to change the type in "**com.demo.alaramdemo**" use Pieter12345 answer(, or just change the name of the folder in the file system)

If you want a more file system like view within eclipse use the "Navigator"-View

Comment: I tried your solution and found one more here --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923002/white-package-icons-in-my-eclipses-package-explorer  but still one blank default package is remaining .I just want to hide it any how. This is happening with all import of project even new one also :(

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got the answer to this, With the help of a post above by Stefan

and a solution mentioned here on below link http://www.coderanch.com/t/105581/vc/Eclipse-hide-empty-packages

actually i had to create filters available on a inverted triangle in package explorer header.
In that u have to check filter of empty package , empty parent package etc
it worked for me.

[image: Filters applying screenshots]

Thanks all for the help ... :)